# What is the EAN's signature mechanism ? They use MD5?

Tags: md5, signature

I see EAN'S signature's document like the following:

http://developer.ean.com/docs/getting-started/api-authentication

```
SIG = MD5("{APIKey}{APISecret}{UnixTimestamp in second}")
```

> When using the digital signature, the value of sig is calculated by generating an MD5 hash made up of the API key, the API user’s shared secret, and a UNIX timestamp.
>
> The system accepts timestamps up to five minutes before or after the server timestamp to accommodate for reasonable clock drift.

And they show the sample url only contains ApiKey, not include timestamp

> http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?cid=[yourCID]&apiKey=[yourAPIKey]&sig=[youSigValue]&minorRev=[current minorRev #]&customerUserAgent=[xxx]&customerIpAddress=[xxx]&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&hotelId=201252

My question is :

How they detected my request whether in five minutes before or after the server time???

Compare MD5 result 600 times??

Comment: Probably yes. Generating a MD5 is a relatively cheap operation and if the key is valid they only have to keep calculating it until they find a match.

Comment: Wow...if really like this, they are too lower...